# Is there a way to get all nat gateways in AWS much like ec2.subnets.all()?

Tags: boto3

I know there is a describe_nat_gateways function available in boto3 but that is only helpful if you already have the id's for the network gateways. Are there any plans to search for all existing nat gateways similar to how all subnets are retrieved using ec2.subnets.all()?

Answer (score 3):

When using boto3 you can create resources or clients. To describe_nat_gateways without having the id's (so, listing all of them you have in your region) all you  have to do is:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_nat_gateways()

print(response)
```

You can learn more about the client methods in this link: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I ended up using a filter (vpc_id) on that describe_nat_gateways function and that yielded all of the nat_gateways assigned to each individual vpc. In other words I got all of nat_gateways listed by simply parsing the result dict :)